# Property "ImagePreview cant be found on type "ImageFileInfo"

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2017

I self-learning Visual Studio and C# recently,
so I followed this example

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/basics/xaml-basics-adaptive-layout

and had the error that on the title

Here is source code (I think it's exactly same as in the link)

```
<Page x:Name="page"
      x:Class="PhotoLab.MainPage"
      <!-- skip -->
    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageGridView_DefaultItemTemplate">
        <!-- skip -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageGridView_MobileItemTemplate"
                      x:DataType="local:ImageFileInfo">
                <!-- skip -->
                <Image x:Name="ItemImage"
                       Source="{x:Bind ImagePreview}"
                       Stretch="UniformToFill">
                <!-- skip -->
        </DataTemplate>
        <!-- skip -->
    </Page.Resources>
    <RelativePanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <!-- skip -->
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
           <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Key="LargeWindow">
                    <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                        <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="{StaticResource LargeWindowSnapPoint}"/>
                    <!-- skip -->
                    </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
   </RelativePanel>
</Page>
```

p.s One more thing, why I can't use x:Key on << VisualState >>?
It makes error too

Comment: Apparently there is no ImagePreview property in class ImageFileInfo.

Comment: Clemens// that sounds sad...... and then where is ImagePreview?

Comment: How should I possibly know that. It's your code, isn't it?

Comment: Clemens// Actually, Technically, Literally, it is not my own code, because I followed just wrote in microsoft example :(

Comment: Did you download the "starter code" from GitHub?

Comment: Clemens// Yup, and add some codes, exactly same in the documents above the link. what I added are the <<DataTemplate>> and <<RelativePanel>>, <<VisualStateGroup>> etc

Answer (score 0):

I just watch the sample on Github. There is no 'ImagePreview' property in `ImageFileInfo` class.

I think this property is a getter on the File image source.
So this property should be the same type as the result of the method:

```
public async Task<BitmapImage> GetImageSourceAsync()
```

So I suggest you:

- to add a 'traditional' property, `ImagePreview` like this:

  ```
  private BitmapImage _imagePreview;

  // ...

  public BitmapImage ImagePreview
  {
      get => _imagePreview;
      private set => SetProperty(ref _imagePreview, value);
  }
  ```
- then you have to implement an async method **to load this image** into the `ImagePreview` property. This method exists, it's GetImageSourceAsync(). So, somewhere you want in your code, call this:

  ```
  fileImage.ImagePreview = await fileImage.GetImageSourceAsync();
  ```

Comment: very thanks, it works // actually I solved this problem, not using preview, just bind actual images. it worked too :)